# Which synchronization model to use for multiple threads waiting for a thread

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I have a program where one thread creates a file and other threads are waiting for the file to be created. Once the file is created the other threads will read this file and continue their processing. I want these other threads to run in parallel. The thread that creates the file does not know how many threads are waiting for it. What synchronization model should I use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, you might look at the inotify interface. This allows a thread / threads to watch a filesystem for something happening (e.g. a file being created). [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Or you could use a pub/sub pattern in ZeroMQ; the creating thread makes the file, then sends some sort of message into a PUB socket. Whichever SUBscribers are listening would all get that message (they'd be blocked waiting for the message in the meantime), and then read the file. This would probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not known upfront how many threads are going to be waiting, you can use a the 'completion' pattern - this is a mutex-protected flag, with an condition variable to signal changes:

```
int done = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

To wait for the completion (ie. in the threads waiting for the file to be created), you use the condition variable to wait for the flag to be set:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
while (!done)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

To signal the completion (ie. in the thread that has created the file), you set the flag and signal the condition variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
done = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

You could wrap this all up in a 'completion' data type if you wanted.